# Does pyspark tfidf transformation maintain index positions?

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running the series of functions:

```
hashingTF = HashingTF()
documents = sc.parallelize(df.content_list.values)
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
tf.cache()
idf = IDF(minDocFreq=2).fit(tf)
tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
```

However I am not sure if these remain in the same position they were inserted in.

Is there a way to map these back to their original value or index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to `zip` `documents` with the result of `IDF.transform`:

```
combined = documents.zip(tfidf)
```

Since neither `HashingTF.transform` nor `IDF.transform` shuffles the data this is a safe transformation and corresponding objects will be combined into tuples.

In general case if you have two RDDs with a common ancestor and there neither one has been shuffled (all transformations has been expressed using only `mapPartitions`) then relationships between partitions should be preserved. Furthermore if number of elements hasn't changed (no `filters` or `flatMaps`) then order of values and number of elements per partition should be preserved as well. In case like this you use `zip` to reconnect data.

Otherwise you add unique keys before splitting and use `join` to connect data again.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a lot more confidence in my operations